# Python 3 : Global name 'inSet' is not defined

Tags: python-3.x, nameerror

I've just began learning Python 3 about 2 weeks ago. I decided to make a basic text game However, I've run into a bug in the code that I can't seem to fix, and that I can't find anywhere else. When I run my game (code incoming), I get this error:

```
Welcome to the room. This is the room in which this game takes place

Press enter to continue.

What would you like to do? Type HELP for your options

HELP

Traceback (most recent call last):


File "C:/Users/Michael/Desktop/mess.py", line 35, in <module>
inputFunc()


File "C:/Users/Michael/Desktop/mess.py", line 7, in inputFunc
inputExam()


File "C:/Users/Michael/Desktop/mess.py", line 9, in inputExam
if (inSet == "LOOK"):

NameError: global name 'inSet' is not defined
```

Here is the code for my game:

```
# functions:
def youLose():
    print("You lost.")
def inputFunc():
    print("What would you like to do? Type HELP for your options")
    inSet = input()
    inputExam()
def inputExam():
    if (inSet == "LOOK"):
        print("You are in a room. There is a door in front of you. You have a key in your hand. There is a slip of paper on the ground.")
        inputFunc()
    elif (inSet == "HELP"):
        print("Use LOOK to examine your surroundings. Use OPEN to open things. Use EXAMINE to examine things. Use QUIT to quit the game. Remember to use ALL CAPS so the processor can understand you")
        inputFunc()
    elif (inSet == "EXAMINE PAPER"):
        print("The paper reads: 'There is only one winning move'")
        inputFunc()
    elif (inSet == "OPEN DOOR"):
        print("You open the door using your key. There is a bright light on the other side, blinding you. You feel a familiar feeling as you realize that you have died.")
        input("Press enter to continue.")
        youLose()
    elif (inSet == "EXAMINE DOOR"):
        print("A simple oaken door.")
        inputFunc()
    elif (inSet == "QUIT"):
        print("You hear a clicking of gears. You realize that the only winning move is not to play. You Win!")
    elif (inSet == "EXAMINE KEY"):
        print("A small, brass key that looks to fit the lock on the door.")
        inputFunc()
    else:
        print("Syntax Error")
# base:
print("Welcome to the room. This is the room in which this game takes place")
input("Press enter to continue.")
inputFunc()
```

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is variable scope:

```
def inputFunc():
    print("What would you like to do? Type HELP for your options")
    inSet = input()
    inputExam()

def inputExam():
    if (inSet == "LOOK"):
        ...
```

`inSet` is defined in `inputFunc`. It doesn't exist outside of `inputFunc`, so you cannot use it in `inputExam`.

You can either make it a global:

```
inSet = ''

def inputFunc():
    global inSet

    print("What would you like to do? Type HELP for your options")
    inSet = input()
    inputExam()

def inputExam():
    global inSet

    if (inSet == "LOOK"):
        ...
```

Or pass it as an argument to `inputExam`:

```
def inputFunc():
    print("What would you like to do? Type HELP for your options")
    inSet = input()
    inputExam(inSet)

def inputExam(inSet):
    if (inSet == "LOOK"):
        ...
```

I would go with the latter.